# Thread Safe Event Calls

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

A common practice to avoid race conditions (in multi-threaded apps) when triggering events is this:

```
EventHandler<EventArgs> temp = SomeEvent;
if (temp != null) temp(e);

"Remember that delegates are immutable and this is why this technique works in theory. However, what a lot of developers don't realize is that this code could be optimized by the compiler to remove the local temp variable entirely. If this happens, this version of the code is identical to the first version, so a NullReferenceException is still possible."
```

The problem (according to the book) is that "this code could be optimized by the compiler to remove the local temp variable entirely. If this happens, this version of the code is identical to the first version, so a NullReferenceException is still possible"

According to CLR via C#, here is a better way to force the compiler to copy the event pointer.

```
virtual void OnNewMail(NewMailEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs> temp =
                          Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref NewMail, null, null);
    if (temp != null) 
        temp(this, e);
}
```

> Here, CompareExchange changes the NewMail reference to null if it is null and does not alter NewMail if it is not null. In other words, CompareExchange doesn't change the value in NewMail at all, but it does return the value inside NewMail in an atomic, thread-safe way.
>       Richter, Jeffrey (2010-02-12). CLR via C# (p. 265). OReilly Media - A. Kindle Edition.

I am on .Net 4.0 framework, and not sure how this can possibly work, because Interlocked.CompareExchange expects a reference to a location, not a reference to a event.

Either there is an error in the book, or I misinterpreted it. Has anyone implemented this method? Or have a better way to prevent race conditions here?

UPDATE

it was my mistake, the iterlocked code works. i just had wrong casting specified, but according to Bradley (below) it is not necessary in .net 2.0 and up on windows.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx might be interesting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler (or JIT) is not allowed to optimize that `if/temp` away (in CLR 2.0 and later); the [CLR 2.0 Memory Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/cc163715.aspx#S5) does not allow reads from the heap to be introduced (rule #2).

Thus, `MyEvent` can not be read a second time; the value of `temp` must be read in the `if` statement.

See [my blog post](http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/11/events_and_threads_part_4.html) for an extended discussion of this situation, and an explanation of why the standard pattern is fine.

However, if you are running on a non-Microsoft CLR (e.g., mono) that doesn't provide the CLR 2.0 memory model guarantees (but only follows the ECMA memory model), or you're running on Itanium (which has a notoriously weak hardware memory model), you will need code like Richter's to eliminate a potential race condition.

In regards to your question about `Interlocked.CompareExchange`, the syntax `public event EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs> NewMail` is just C# syntactic sugar for declaring a private field of type `EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs>` and a public event that has `add` and `remove` methods. The `Interlocked.CompareExchange` call reads the value of the private `EventHandler<NewMailEventArgs>` field, so this code does compile and work as Richter describes; it's just unnecessary in the Microsoft CLR.

Comment: i updated my example with comments from author. if what you're saying is true, it directly conflicts with what Jeffrey Richter is saying. And i have caught him with inaccurate statements in this book before.. i'd just like to confirm the correct way of doing this..

Comment: Only in the windows/.Net complier/JIT, this is untrue for Mono. http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm

Comment: @caesay: Good point; I did address that in my blog post, but not in the answer; I'll update.

Comment: @SonicSoul: Yes, I am directly contradicting Richter. IIRC, _CLR via C#_ is the book where he claimed that calling `IDisposable.Dispose` is unnecessary, and I completely disagree with that too. :-)

Comment: @BradleyGrainger, so you're saying the very first example is perfectly fine, or should still use the Interlocked (on windows)?

Comment: @SonicSoul: Yes, the first example is guaranteed to run correctly under Microsoft's CLR on Windows.

Comment: This is an old thread, but on the IDisposable.Dispose comment from @BradleyGrainger: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kimhamil/archive/2008/11/05/when-to-call-dispose.aspx [Bradely is himself has commented on that thread] - Jeffery didn't make a blanket statement about IDisposable - he had a valid point for some special cases.

Answer (score 4):

Now this is only a partial answer to your question, because I can not comment on using Interlocked.CompareExchange, however I think this information could be useful.

> The problem is that the compiler may optimize that if/temp away,

Well, according to *CLR via C#* (p. 264–265)

> [The] code could be optimized by the compiler to remove the local […] variable entirely. If this happens, this version of the code is identical to the [version that references the event twice], so a NullReferenceException is still possible.

So, it is ***possible***, however, it important to know that Microsoft’s just-in-time (JIT) compiler does not **ever** optimize away the local variable. While this could possibly change, it is unlikely, because it would probably break a lot of applications.

This is because .Net has a strong memory model: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx#S5

> Reads and writes cannot be introduced.

and

> The model does not allow reads to be introduced, however, because this would imply refetching a value from memory, and in low-lock code memory could be changing.

However, Mono, which follows a [much weaker memory model](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm), could optimize that local variable away.

Bottom line: Unless you're planning on using Mono, don't worry about it.

And even then, that behavior can be suppressed with volatile declarations.

Comment: you're correct.. i jumped to a conclusion there. adjusted my post and removed that "optimized away" statement.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you miss interpreted. Location mean just a pointer to object reference [*msdn version:The destination object that is compared with comparand and possibly replaced.*]. Following code work fine in .NEt 4.0

```
public class publisher
{

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> TestEvent;
    protected virtual void OnTestEvent(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<EventArgs> temp = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref TestEvent, null, null);
        if (temp != null)
            temp(this,e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I you look at the IL produced you'll see that the method is called like this

```
IL_000d:  ldsflda    class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler`1<class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs> ConsoleApplication1.Program::MyEvent
IL_0012:  ldnull
IL_0013:  ldnull
IL_0014:  call       !!0 [mscorlib]System.Threading.Interlocked::CompareExchange<class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler`1<class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs>>(!!0&,!!0,!!0)
```

see that `ldsflda` - my event is static but it's loading the address of a **field**. That field is the auto generated delegate field which the compiler generates for each event.

the field is defined like this:

```
.field private static class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler`1<class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs> MyEvent
```