# Calling an asynchronous method without await recommended?

Tags: c#, async-await

I wrote a small computer game where you can mine gold. The game is used to understand asynchronous programming with async and await. The loop menu offers three options: Mine gold, view evaluation, and exit.

The GoldMining method makes heavy use of the CPU. The probability to get one gram of gold during a mining is 1 in 10.000.000. Therefore it takes a long time until 1000g of gold are mined.

You start mining gold asynchronously from the loop menu. Then you can use option 2 (show evaluation) at any time to see the amount of gold you have mined so far.

Although the GoldMining method is very time consuming, the loop menu does not freeze. That's nice. However, I call the asynchronous method GoldMining without await. Now my question: Is this way of calling asynchronous methods to prevent the program from freezing a recommended approach?

```
//Evaluation contains the gold stock that was mined in total. 
//The class definition is done at the very bottom.
Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation();
await Main(evaluation);

static async Task Main(Evaluation evaluation){    
    string input="start";
    while(input!="exit"){
        Console.WriteLine("choose an option:");
        Console.WriteLine("1 gold mining");
        Console.WriteLine("2 show evaluation");
        Console.WriteLine("3 exit.");
        input=Console.ReadLine();
        switch(input){
            //Call GoldMining without await
            case "1":GoldMining(evaluation);break;
            case "2":Console.WriteLine(evaluation.gold);;break;
            case "exit":input="exit"; break;
            default:input="exit";break;
        }
    }
 }  

static async Task GoldMining(Evaluation evaluation){
    Random rand= new Random();
    int yield=0;
    Console.WriteLine("Gold mining begins");
    await Task.Run(() =>
        {  
           while(yield<1000){
                    int chance =rand.Next(0,10000000); 
                    if(chance==1){yield++;evaluation.gold++;}
            } 2
        }); 
    Console.WriteLine("1000g Gold minded");   
}  
public class Evaluation{
    public int gold{get;set;}
    public Evaluation(){
        this.gold=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: A CPU intensive method is not a good fit for async. You need real multithreading

Comment: [Async != Concurrent != Parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4844637/9363973). As a rule of thumb, use async for tasks which mainly consist of waiting, i.e waiting on a IO operation (be it from disk or from a network or anything else), use concurrent or parallel for tasks which mainly consist of doing something (i.e heavy calculations)

Comment: As a side note, the name `Main` has a [special meaning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line) in C#. I would suggest to rename your `static async Task Main(Evaluation evaluation)` method to something else (preferably to something meaningful).

Comment: I'm a bit irritated because I learned from a couple of Youtube videos that the big advantage of asynchronous programming is that the program doesn't freeze while it's handling a complex task. But now when I put await in front of the GoldMining method, the program freezes. Which is pretty stupid.

Comment: Also the convention for naming [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) in C# is to use PascalCase. `public int Gold { get; set; }` is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The game is used to understand asynchronous programming with async and await... The GoldMining method makes heavy use of the CPU.

Asynchronous code is not a natural fit with CPU-bound methods. For CPU-bound methods, you want parallel code or multithreading.

If you want to learn asynchronous code in a more natural way, use an I/O-bound operation. E.g., an HTTP request to `https://deelay.me/10000/https://google.com/`.

Note that `Task.Run` is a form of multithreading (pushing work onto the thread pool). So your code is already using both multithreading and asynchrony - which is fine, but complicates things while learning.

> However, I call the asynchronous method GoldMining without await. Now my question: Is this way of calling asynchronous methods to prevent the program from freezing a recommended approach?

No, certainly not. This is a kind of "fire and forget", which is dangerous in general. You almost always want to call `await`; if you do need to spin off a separate "top-level task", then you normally want to capture the task into a local variable and `await` it *later*. Otherwise, your app may exit before the operation is complete, and also you may not be aware of any exceptions that have happened.

> I'm a bit irritated because I learned from a couple of Youtube videos that the big advantage of asynchronous programming is that the program doesn't freeze while it's handling a complex task.

You're currently writing a Console application. While Console apps are nice for learning *most* technologies, I believe using Console for learning `async` is not a good idea. Console apps *can* be asynchronous, but it's a very unusual environment for asynchronous applications. A much more natural environment is a client app (UI) or a server app (ASP.NET), both of which have framework-level support for asynchrony.

So, when the videos mention not "freezing", they're referring to how `await` (on a UI app) can keep the UI thread free to handle other messages. Since a Console app doesn't have a UI message loop, the same benefit doesn't apply there. You can build it, but it's way better IMO to learn proper `async`/`await` with either a UI app or an ASP.NET app first.

Comment: I want to emphasize that Microsoft itself explains the principle of async and await using a [command line application](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) as an example. Unfortunately, I still have not understood async and await. If I set an await in line 13 before calling the GoldMining function, the program freezes. What would have to be changed in my example, so that it corresponds to the recommended principle of async and await?

Comment: @ZJ: You can think of `await` as "asynchronous wait". So the `while` loop won't continue until the `await`ed item completes. In the "recommended principle", the `while` loop belongs to the application framework (i.e., it's the Win32 message loop), and your code can just do an `await` and the application remains responsive. If you're looking for an intro, I have [one on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: I hope that my question is not a bit exaggerated but what would I have to change so that the While loop does not block when calling await GoldMining()?

Comment: Well, the simple answer is to fire-and-forget (i.e., no `await`), or to save the `Task` in a local variable and `await` it later. The complex answer is to write a framework: something that `async` can schedule asynchronous work to, and that will (a)wait for that asynchronous work to complete before exiting. This is an extremely advanced and rare use case. You can use my [`AsyncContext` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/0361015459938f2eb8f3c1ad1021d19ee01c93a4/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Context/AsyncContext.cs#L160) if you don't want to write your own.

Answer (score 1):

So, first of all your code is not thread safe. You need to use `Interlocked.Increment(ref evaluation.gold)` instead of `evaluation.gold++` and volatile read (or even dummy `Interlocked.CompareExchange`, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24808291/reading-an-int-thats-updated-by-interlocked-on-other-threads)) at case "2". This may or may not matter, depending on whether your task scheduler is multithreaded or not (it is by default). Well, actually if your scheduler is single threaded then your code wouldn't work at all, due to an infinite loop (adding `await Task.Yield();` inside the while loop in `Main()` would fix that). Either way, the rule of thumb is: always write a thread safe code when doing async.

> Now my question: Is this way of calling asynchronous methods to prevent the program from freezing a recommended approach?

Yes, it is a good idea to spawn a background worker, in fact there's no other way to achieve that (I mean, you can spawn a thread instead of async task, but the idea is the same). And no, it is not a good idea to leave it without supervision. What if it fails? You have no option to react to it, even to log an error. What if `GoldMining()` is called multiple times? Maybe it is allowed, but without limit?

You could keep the result of calling `GoldMining()` around (without `await`) and check its status from time to time. You could keep it in a list and disallow too many. But perhaps a better approach would be to have a separate queue, a separate thread/async task that operates on it and also gracefuly handles all the errors. All of that wrapped into a single class.